# SDL2 GUI (same window)

Tags: gui, sdl, sdl2

I have a problem: I working on a simple game and want to use some GUI (think of simple input for player name, etc). I've googled a lot of GUIs that can be used with SDL, but:

1. Most of them are using OpenGL while I'm using SDL2 render system. Docs say I can't mix these two, so I need to render GUI in a separate window. I know I can make it borderless and always-on-top, but I still need to manage this as a separate window (e.g. if main window moves, I need to move the gui window, etc, basically, I need to implement the childing myself). That makes me sad.
2. Those few which are using SDL as render (without OpenGL) either abandoned / unfinished / can't be compiled / etc or I can't figure out how to mix them with my rendering.

What I want to achieve: to render GUI in some place on the screen (think of a sidebar) and game stuff on the rest of the screen. Like:

```
SDL_Window* w = ...;
SDL_Renderer * r = ...;

while(running)
{
    renderGui(r, 0, 0, 100, 100); // Minimap located at 0,0 of size 100
    renderGameScreen(r, 100, 100, 100, 100); // Rest of the game located at 100, 100
}
```

Is there a way to do that? How GUI supposed to be used in alongside the SDL? May be my design is broken.

Sorry, I'm completely novice and may mix the things. Thanks.

**Update**:

Thanks for your answers. Quick update: I've tried so far:

1. nanogui-sdl - it uses opengl context, I was not able to mix it with SDL 2d render: it either flickers (because opengl and sdl fight for the screen and over-drawing the contents) or just draws the either thing: ui or game screen. Moreover, it crashes on some controls (like color-picker) and significantly affects rendering time (it drops 2-3 times when I add nanogui rendering with a couple of basic widgets)
2. nuklear - the same thing as with nanogui
3. I was not able to compile ToT KiWi - there are some syntax error (like `#elsif` instead of `#else if` or `#elif` so I'm not ever sure it can be compiled at all).

I'm going to try: imgui, kiss and gwen (gwork).

In the end, I can switch my drawing to opengl (fortunately I need some basic primitives, like circles, rectangles, triangles, etc, nothing complex) if I can't find a UI to work with SDL 2d render.

**Update 2**:

Sorry for not selecting the answer - was very busy during the week. I marked answer as accepted. I also tried to upvote both answers, since they are both useful, but I don't have enough reputation to do that. Thanks.

For those who wondering is I solve the problem: yes, kind of. I've switched over to SFML. I really like SDL and know it's very stable and mature, but I really need basic graphics for my pet project, so I'm OK with SFML too. It makes working with OpenGL a bit easier, so I can adopt the GUI library.

Comment: I understand the need for a third party gui that can integrate painless with your game. The examples provided in the answers so far should be considered as options. Regarding the minimap, I don't think the controls/widgets provided by any GUI can help to render it, maybe if there is a GUI that provides drawing functions over a canvas, but there are separate libraries for that (cairo, etc). I will look into providing an example as answer. SDL supports clip regions (SDL_RenderSetClipRect), so implementing the minimap without a GUI library should be possible without a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you tried a few, but did not list them. Which ones did you try?

These are SDL2 based, without OpenGL, and are actively maintained:

- [kiss_sdl](https://github.com/actsl/kiss_sdl)
- [KiWi](https://github.com/mobius3/KiWi)

Answer (score 1):

PDCurses ( https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses ) might be worth investigation.  It's strictly text mode, but there's a SDL back end.  There's an example that comes with it that shows using SDL graphics with PDCurses text user interface functionality.